# Letra "m" na versão do Google Chrome para Windows

Tags: google-chrome

Alguém sabe o significado da letra "m" ao final da versão do Google Chrome? Procurei por respostas em outras lugares, mais ainda não consegui uma boa informação.

Ex. 32.0.1700.102 m

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score 15):

"m" significa "multi-install".

Veja o trecho do código-fonte do Google Chrome:

```c
// Return a human readable modifier for the version string, e.g.
// the channel (dev, beta, stable). Returns true if this operation succeeded,
// on success, channel contains one of "", "unknown", "dev" or "beta" (unless
// it is a multi-install product, in which case it will return "m",
// "unknown-m", "dev-m", or "beta-m").

static bool GetChromeChannelAndModifiers(bool system_install,
                                       base::string16* channel);
```

Fonte: https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/installer/util/google_update_settings.h#l179

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]